# Taking power from an electric range

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I need 20A 250V for an espresso Machine.
I have 50A 250V going to my electric Range.
Can hook the espresso machine on the same line as the Electric Range ?

What bother me is that the 20A 250V espresso will be "protected" by the 50A breaker .

Comment: Is there a range using the circuit? Where in the world are you?

Comment: Here in the U.S. Unless you changed your breaker to 20A it would be a code violation. Since you are probably across the pond check into your "tap" rules some times it is acceptable to tap a higher power circuit like a range to power the lower voltage / amperage  controls. Here they need to be in the same unit not sure about other places.

Comment: Here's a question about USA code - this is NOT a recommendation!  What if someone took that 50A oven circuit and brought it to a sub-panel.   In the sub-panel put a 50A breaker to serve the oven and a 20A breaker to serve other outlets.  Would this be NEC legal?

Comment: @WolfHarper Maybe, but you'd have an ugly panel in your kitchen, and you'd have to put the panel where you have the proper working space around it and accessibility. You might also run into trouble at Thanksgiving, when you're cooking turkey, pies, etc., and you try to make an espresso.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! You need a new dedicated circuit & dedicated outlet for that, essentially you must treat it as another Range or Dishwasher type of Appliance.